# UsedRange.Rows.Count shows different number than the actual

Tags: excel, vba

I need some expert advice on VBA code. I have created a procedure to compare two short reports (the same format, generated from the system). I used the `for` loop starting from the first row until the last one using `UsedRange.Rows.Count`. The problem I have is that UsedRange.Rows.Count always return 30 even though the reports are generally shorter than that - usually around 20-25 rows. It returns 30 even if I clear the content inside these rows. It only returns the correct number when I permanently delete the blank rows up to row 30.

Why is that happening? It bothers me because also for some reason the macro highlights the blank rows (from the last actually used to row 30) showing them as a difference between the reports, while they exist and are the same (blank) in both.

Thank you

Comment: Can you give some more details?  Are there formula's remaining in rows 25-30, just not showing as data missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UsedRange` will expand to include all cells that Excel registers as containing **any** data.  Values, formulae, formatting — even (and I suspect that this may be what is happening here) a cell that has had a value deleted from it.  Anything outside of `UsedRange` is treated as not yet officially existing yet.

As an analogy, this is the difference between an *empty* box, and *no* box (with the worksheet cells being boxes).  `UsedRange` tells you where the last box is, even if you've emptied it (with `Value = ""` or `ClearContent`); only **deleting** the Rows/Columns/Cells will get rid of the box itself.

There are *many* **much better** ways to get the size of your data than by using `UsedRange` (although, it at least provides an Upper Bound)

For example, if your data is contiguous, then you can select a single cells (e.g. `Range("A1")` / `Cells(1,1)`), and get the [`CurrentRegion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion) (`Cells(1,1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count`).  Or, if you know a column that always contains data, you can use `End(..)` to find the bottommost cell (`Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row`)